# Which formula should I use to place a user ID in one column based on a name in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Edited to reformat: I have 530 rows of employees in a spreadsheet, each has their manager listed in column H. There are 15 managers. In Column I, I need to assign an auditor to review each employee. Auditors should be assigned based on who the manager is. Each auditor has a unique "ID."

I want to determine if there is a function that can look at column H, and based on the name therein, return the corresponding auditor's unique ID.

I tried VLOOKUP by making a new worksheet with the first column as the manager name, second column with the auditor ID, but it returns errors (probably due to incorrect syntax)?

Comment: Please take a minute to [edit] your question with what you are trying to accomplish and what you've tried. My questions to you are; Are there 10 "user names" per manager or 10 to be divided between the managers? Where are the "user names" stored? How is excel to know what "user name" goes with what manager/employee?

Comment: Please post the exact VLOOKUP formula you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is set up another sheet with Managers in 1 column and the corresponding username in the next column. From there, you'll want column K to do a VLOOKUP using column H, going to the 2nd sheet and pulling the 2nd column.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Formula used =VLOOKUP($H2,Alignment!$A$2:$B$15,2,FALSE) with alignment as the new sheet.